# With React Styled Components, how do I declare the colour based on state collected via useSelector?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsx, styled-components

I'm using Styled Components in my app. I am collecting state via useSelector using React-Redux, this state returns either a 0 or 1 - 0 telling me the app is currently in light mode, 1 telling me the app is currently in dark mode.

How do I edit the style based on the value? I have tried the following...

```
const Logo = styled(motion.h1)`
  color: ${themeColour ? "white" : "black"};
`;
```

However, this didn't work as the variable exists inside a function. I then tried to style the h1 component directly in the JSX like this...

```
<h1 style={{color: ${themeColour ? "white" : "black"}}}>
```

I got the following error...

```
"./src/components/Nav.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\james\Documents\Web Development\Portfolio\Project 1 - RelaxStation\Code\relax-station\src\components\Nav.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (14:26)"
```

Could someone help me figure this out please? Below is my full code for the component (please note I couldn't indent it correctly when pasting the code in here, but it is correct in Visual Studio Code)...

```
// Libraries
import styled from "styled-components";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

// Redux
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Nav = () => {
  // Get current theme colour code - Gives a 0 for light mode or a 1 for dark mode
  const themeColour = useSelector((state) => state.theme);

  return (
<StyledNav>
  <Logo>
    Relax<span>Station</span>
  </Logo>

  <div className="main">
    <h4>MAIN</h4>
    <ul className="main-links">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Artists</li>
      <li>Albums</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div className="playlists">
    <h4>PLAYLISTS</h4>
    <ul className="playlist-links">
      <li>Early morning</li>
      <li>Studying</li>
      <li>Driving</li>
      <li>Ambience</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</StyledNav>
  );
};

const StyledNav = styled(motion.nav)`
  position: static;
  width: 10rem;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 95vh;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
`;

const Logo = styled(motion.h1)`
  color: ${themeColour ? "white" : "black"};
`;

export default Nav;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass on the themeColor as a prop to tthe Logo component while render

```
  <Logo themeColor={themeColor}>
    Relax<span>Station</span>
  </Logo>
```

and then use it with styled component like

```
const Logo = styled(motion.h1)`
  color: ${props => props.themeColour? "white" : "black"};
`;
```

For the h1 tag your code didn't work because your syntax was incorrect

Below is the correct usage

```
<h1 style={{color: themeColour ? "white" : "black"}}>
```

Comment: That all worked great, thank you so much for your help. I didn't know you could pass props down like that to styled components. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Glad to have helped.